# Curve fitting using scipy with backward dependency

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to do a curve fit for a transient thermal data. I have equations which will calculate the delta temperature in every timepoint. This delta has to be added to the temperature from previous timepoint to get the temperature at any given timepoint.

ie; T<sub>n</sub> = T<sub>n-1</sub> + delta.

If I express using the [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) from scipy's documentation for `curve_fit`. It would be something similar.

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c #+ func(x[n-1], a, b, c) <<< need help here

xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
y = func(xdata, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)
np.random.seed(1729)
y_noise = 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=xdata.size)
ydata = y + y_noise
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
print(popt)
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-',
         label='fit: a=%5.3f, b=%5.3f, c=%5.3f' % tuple(popt))
```

Any lead on how to achive this is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a differential equation you need to find the integral before fitting it to data. Unless the data is also differential, in which case you can just fit.

The question seems to imply that in your case `delta` is given by `a * np.exp(-b * x) + c`, which makes the resulting y values easy to compute because `curve_fit` passes *all* the x values to `func` and expects it to return *all* the y values anyway.

```
def delta_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

def func(x, a, b, c):
    y = np.empty(x.shape)
    y[0] = delta_func(0, a, b, c)
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        y[i] = y[i-1] + delta_func(x[i], a, b, c)
    return y
```

This was for illustration. You can obtain the same result with [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html):

```
def func(x, a, b, c):
    return np.cumsum(a * np.exp(-b * x) + c)
```